# iPhone SDK: Trying out 4.0

Tags: iphone

I am thinking of buying a new iPod Touch to try out 4.0 multi-tasking. Can someone provide a link that describes how I get iPhone OS 4.0 on the device?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you need to buy an iphone developer subscription (99$/year) to get the beta version (see : [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/index.action))